# Workbench access - how to limit which which menus user can add to

Tags: routes, users, workflows, nodes, workbench

I have a workbench workflow system that's setup using a taxonomy to manage the sections. Is it possible to restrict which menu items a node can be added to, depending on a user's section.

Even without Workbench access, any suggestions of limiting how to restrict which menus/menu items users can add to would be appreciated.

Comment: What about [Organic Groups Menu (OG Menu)](http://drupal.org/project/og_menu)?